# Linux `getcontext` returns incorrect stack state

Tags: c, linux, stack

I'm trying to use Linux' `getcontext` syscall to get the current context, particularly the current stack. I understand that there could be different contexts particularly when signal handlers are concerned. However, in a simple program with `main` and a few functions, what does the `ucontext_t`'s stack point to?

Here is a simple example I ran:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

// Unnecessary
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void print_ucstack(stack_t *ustk) {
  printf("ss_sp = %p, ss_size = 0x%lx, ss_flags = %x\n", ustk->ss_sp, ustk->ss_size, ustk->ss_flags);
}

int print_context() {

  ucontext_t ctx;
  if(getcontext(&ctx) != 0)
    return -1;

  greg_t *regs = ctx.uc_mcontext.gregs;
  printf("Actual stack pointer = %llx\n", regs[REG_RSP]);
  print_ucstack(&ctx.uc_stack);

  return 0;
}

void print_map() {
  char filebuf[4096];
  int fd = open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY);
  int nbytes;
  if(fd != -1) {
    while((nbytes = read(fd, filebuf, sizeof(filebuf))) != 0) 
      printf("%.*s", nbytes, filebuf);
  }
  close(fd);
}

int main() {
  print_map();
  print_context();
}
```

In the above example, I print `/proc/self/maps` to get the correct process layout. Also, I print the real stack pointer from `uc_mcontext`. Finally, I print the stack pointer from `uc_stack.ss_sp`.

Here is an example output:

```
558e93a85000-558e93a86000 r--p 00000000 103:06 1449251                   /tmp/stackrelocate/stackrelocate
558e93a86000-558e93a87000 r-xp 00001000 103:06 1449251                   /tmp/stackrelocate/stackrelocate
558e93a87000-558e93a88000 r--p 00002000 103:06 1449251                   /tmp/stackrelocate/stackrelocate
558e93a88000-558e93a89000 r--p 00002000 103:06 1449251                   /tmp/stackrelocate/stackrelocate
558e93a89000-558e93a8a000 rw-p 00003000 103:06 1449251                   /tmp/stackrelocate/stackrelocate
7fcb74663000-7fcb74685000 r--p 00000000 103:06 1311717                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7fcb74685000-7fcb747fd000 r-xp 00022000 103:06 1311717                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7fcb747fd000-7fcb7484b000 r--p 0019a000 103:06 1311717                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7fcb7484b000-7fcb7484f000 r--p 001e7000 103:06 1311717                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7fcb7484f000-7fcb74851000 rw-p 001eb000 103:06 1311717                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
7fcb74851000-7fcb74857000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcb7487c000-7fcb7487d000 r--p 00000000 103:06 1311305                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7fcb7487d000-7fcb748a0000 r-xp 00001000 103:06 1311305                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7fcb748a0000-7fcb748a8000 r--p 00024000 103:06 1311305                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7fcb748a9000-7fcb748aa000 r--p 0002c000 103:06 1311305                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7fcb748aa000-7fcb748ab000 rw-p 0002d000 103:06 1311305                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
7fcb748ab000-7fcb748ac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffdb8771000-7ffdb8792000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffdb87fb000-7ffdb87fe000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffdb87fe000-7ffdb87ff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Actual stack pointer = 7ffdb8790260
ss_sp = 0x7fcb746682d0, ss_size = 0x7ffdb87904b0, ss_flags = 74855000
```

As you can see, the actual stack pointer is within the stack VMA, whereas the `uc_stack.ss_sp` is in the executable VMA from `libc.so`. The size value is also incorrect.

What is happening here?

- Why is the `uc_stack` member not reflecting the correct values?
- What is the values in `uc_stack` correspond to?
- How can I get the correct **limits (base, size)** of the stack region with syscalls, without reading `/proc/self/maps`?

Comment: Actual stack pointer is whatever is in esp (x86) or SP (arm). What does that show?

Comment: The value in `*ctx.uc_mcontext.gregs` (or `ctx.uc_mcontext.reg_sp`) is the same as the actual stack pointer. So, `get_context` does save the register state correctly. But `ctx.uc_stack` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Why is the uc_stack member not reflecting the correct values?

Because `getcontext` does not initialize `uc_stack`.  It only initializes the bare minimum state required for `setcontext` later.  If I'm reading the various implementations correctly (`getcontext` has to be coded in assembly language for each CPU architecture and ABI supported by the C library) they save *only* the registers defined by the ABI as call-preserved, plus the signal mask.

`uc_stack` exists for *you* to initialize, in between a call to `getcontext` and a call to `makecontext`.

You can confirm this for yourself by adding `memset(&ctx, 0, sizeof ctx);` right before the `getcontext` call, and then observing that `uc_stack.*` are zero afterward.

> - What is the values in uc_stack correspond to?

They are garbage.

> - How can I get the correct limits (base, size) of the stack region with syscalls, without reading /proc/self/maps?

With actual system calls,<sup>1</sup> *you can't*.  There is no good way to do this on Linux currently.  See the discussion starting at https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2022-September/141932.html -- glibc has the same problem internally.

With (extended) pthread *library routines*, you can do this:

```
int get_initial_stack_region(void **p_stackaddr, size_t *p_stacksize)
{
    int perr;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    if ((perr = pthread_getattr_np(pthread_self(), &attr)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_getattr_np: %s\n", strerror(perr));
        return -1;
    }
    if ((perr = pthread_attr_getstack(&attr, p_stackaddr, p_stacksize)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_attr_getstack: %s\n", strerror(perr));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is officially supported, but right now, under the hood, what it's doing is reading and parsing `/proc/self/maps`!

---

<sup>1</sup> `getcontext` etc are not system calls either, they are library routines.  System calls are narrowly defined: the set of operations that is implemented by trapping into the OS kernel.  This command will print an exhaustive list of system calls:

```bash
printf '#include <sys/syscall.h>\n' | 
    gcc -E -dM -xc - |
    sed -ne 's/^#define SYS_\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/p' |
    sort
```

Not all of these correspond directly to functions in the C library, for various reasons including

- it's obsolete but preserved for backward compatibility with old binaries
- the C library wrapper function exists but it has a different name
- nobody has gotten around to adding the C library wrapper function yet
- it's not actually possible to use that syscall safely unless you *are* the C library

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I do have some follow up questions.
1) Why is `getcontext` not responsible for initializing the `uc_stack` field? I get that I can fill it in before calling `makecontext` and then switch to the new context. If this is the only intended use for `uc_stack`, could you point me to any documentation which states this? The existing documentation is annoyingly vague: "initializes the structure pointed to by ucp to the currently active context".

Comment: @TSG As far as I know, filling it in before calling `makecontext` is indeed the only supported use for `uc_stack`. The official specification ([getcontext/setcontext](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcontext.html), [makecontext/swapcontext](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/makecontext.html)) is just as vague, though -- The Open Group never bothered specifying these functions as clearly as modern tastes would like, since they (incorrectly) thought that pthreads were a complete and superior replacement for them.